# How to set stop loss dynamically below a candle pinescript

Tags: pine-script

How do I set stop loss at the hign/low of an entry candle? The value required for loss parameter is in ticks.**Low** and **high** give the price of the instrument (market).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stop` argument which requires a price value.

> **stop (series int/float)** An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a
> specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit
> market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the
> parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss'
> ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The
> default value is 'NaN'.